# Ruby: how to make variables visible inside methods within a block?

Tags: ruby, ruby-block

The following code gives me
`` NameError: undefined local variable or method `dir' ``
in *extract_snapshots* method.

The code is intended to extract snapshots from a video, store them in a created temporary directory, send the snapshots to a service and remove the directory after.

```rb
  def perform
    using_temporary_directory do |dir|
      extract_snapshots
      send_snapshots
    end
  end

  def using_temporary_directory(&b)
    Dir.mktmpdir { |dir| b.call(dir) }
  end

  def extract_snapshots
    system "ffmpeg -i #{video_file_path} -vf fps=1/#{INTERVAL} #{dir}/%04d.jpg"
  end
```

I thought, that *dir* variable should be visible in *extract_snapshots* and *send_snapshots*, because it is on the same level. But it isn't in the scope of those methods.
Is it possible to make *dir* variable visible without doing the following:

```rb
  def perform
    using_temporary_directory do |dir|
      extract_snapshots(dir)
      send_snapshots(dir)
    end
  end
```

?

Comment: Why "make dir variable visible without doing the following"??? Your final example is absolutely the correct way to do it.

Comment: I hoped, to make the code cleaner.

Comment: Less code is not always cleaner code. What you're asking for is how to create an _implicit_ dependency between your methods. That is one of the dirtiest anti-patterns there is.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, using [`attr_accessor`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor):

```
  attr_accessor :dir

  def perform
    using_temporary_directory do
      extract_snapshots
      send_snapshots
    end
  end

  def using_temporary_directory(&b)
    Dir.mktmpdir do |dir| 
      self.dir = dir
      b.call
    end
  ensure # clear the variable when you're finished
    self.dir = nil
  end

  def extract_snapshots
    system "ffmpeg -i #{video_file_path} -vf fps=1/#{INTERVAL} #{dir}/%04d.jpg"
  end
```

For an explanation, `attr_accessor` creates reader and writer methods for you, the equivalent of the following:

```
def dir
  @dir
end

def dir=(val)
  @dir=(val)
end
```

N.B. in my opinion there's nothing wrong with doing it the way you've specified towards the end of your question, so pick and choose as suits your circumstances :)

Hope this helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Comment: More complicated, more error prone, less flexible. This answers the question as asked but is not a good idea in general.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had an idea with an instance variable, but intended to figure out, whether I miss something in understanding of block's local variable scope. In my example *extract_snapshots* is called in the same context with *dir* variable: `using_temporary_directory { |dir| extract_snapshots }`
So, I thought, the variable should be visible inside the method.
But it looks like I understand this correctly: the closure would work, if *dir* variable were visible in the context, where *extract_snapshots* is defined.

Comment: @Max thanks for the feedback, I'd tend to agree - earlier versions of my question were clearer on this, though I trimmed it down for brevity. Hope this has helped clarify the issue somewhat though mSourire :)